# Add values to data frame from For Loop Results

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have this array:

hoods

```
array([['Altos de Arroyo Hondo ,Santo Domingo'],
       ['Arroyo Manzano ,Santo Domingo'],
       ['Atala ,Santo Domingo'],
       ['Bella Vista ,Santo Domingo'],
       ['Buenos Aires-Independencia ,Santo Domingo'],
       ['Cacique ,Santo Domingo'],
       ['Centro de los Héroes ,Santo Domingo'],
       ['Centro Olímpico Duarte ,Santo Domingo'],
       ['Cerros de Arroyo Hondo ,Santo Domingo'],
       ['Ciudad Colonial ,Santo Domingo'],
       ['Ciudad Nueva ,Santo Domingo'],
       ['Veinticuatro de Abril ,Santo Domingo'],
       ['Viejo Arroyo Hondo ,Santo Domingo'],
       ['Villa Consuelo ,Santo Domingo'],
       ['Villa Francisca ,Santo Domingo'],
       ['Villa Juana ,Santo Domingo'],
       ['Villas Agricolas ,Santo Domingo'],
       ['Distrito Nacional ,Santo Domingo']], dtype=object)
```

And I created a empty dataframe:

```
hoods_located  = pd.DataFrame(columns =['Neighborhood', 'Latitude', 'Longitude'])
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to insert values in that data frame from the results of this for loop:

```
for i in hoods:
    geolocator
    location = geolocator.geocode(i)
    latitude = location.latitude
    longitude = location.longitude
    hoods_located.append({'Neighborhood': i, 'Latitude': latitude, 'Longitude': longitude}, ignore_index=True)
```

Using Geopy, the for loop looks for the Lat and Lon for each value of the hoods array but can't figure out how to append those values to the new data frame hoods_located.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to get your data into a dictionary, and read directly into a dataframe; it also removes the need to create an empty dataframe to fill:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

#iterate through hood list and create dictionary
for Neighbourhood in hoods:
    location = geolocator.geocode(Neighbourhood)
    d['latitude'].append(location.latitude)
    d['longitude'].append(location.longitude)
    d['Neighbourhood'].append(Neighbourhood)
    
 #read into dataframe
 pd.DataFrame(d)
```